JEMalloc extension in Duckdb JDBC
I wanted to use jemalloc in duckdb jdbc. But jemalloc extension is not bundled in duckdb jdbc.
As I understood, duckdb is statically linked with jemalloc, and it's should be available on linux platforms. However in duckdb-java there is no jemalloc sources in src/duckdb/extension folder.
Duckdb version: 1.0.0
Duckdb client: jdbc
How can I bundle jemalloc extension with duckdb jdbc.
